# Flutter Phone Authentication FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I just did it by calling verifyPhoneNumber(...) its working using right code.
but wrong code crash app. tried try/catch but is not being caught. following is code

```
codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
 ...
    onPressed: () async{
      final code = _codeController.text.trim();
      AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code
      );
      try{
        UserCredential result = await _firebase_auth.signInWithCredential(credential); //<-- Exception here
        User user = result.user;
        if(user != null){
          await signupParse(token, context);
        }
      } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) { // <---- doesn't get caught here
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        _scaffoldkey.currentState
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid code!')));
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you post error/exception logs as well for reference?

Comment: Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(firebase_auth, com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure use the verification code provided by the user., {code: invalid-verification-code, additionalData: {}, message: The sms verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code sms and be sure use the verification code provided by the user.}, null))

Answer (score 0):

Try with generic **Exception** or **PlatformException** instead of **FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException** for catch

```
onPressed: () async{
  final code = _codeController.text.trim();
  AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code
  );
  try{
    UserCredential result = await _firebase_auth.signInWithCredential(credential); //<-- Exception here
    User user = result.user;
    if(user != null){
      await signupParse(token, context);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) { // <---- doesn't get caught here
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    _scaffoldkey.currentState
    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Invalid code!')));
  }
```

Comment: nope... I did try it earlier as  
both catch (Exception)  and  catch (Exception e) it doesn't work